Release failing due to incorrect path in Azure DevOps
Release failing for NodeJS app in Azure DevOps which appears to be due to incorrect path. Attached yaml and error
YAML:-
steps:
- task: ExtractFiles@1
  displayName: 'Extract files '
  inputs:
    archiveFilePatterns: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_NodeJS-Node.js With Grunt-CI/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    destinationFolder: .

Error:-


I can reproduce the same issue when using the same task settings of the Extract Files task.

The cause of the issue is that the option: cleanDestinationFolder in the Extract Files task is set to true by default.
When you set the destinationFolder to ., it will clean all files in the $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)  folder(including zip file) before unzipping the files.
In this case, the zip file will not be found by the task.
To solve this issue, you need to set cleanDestinationFolder to false in the  Extract Files task.
For example:
steps:
- task: ExtractFiles@1
  displayName: 'Extract files '
  inputs:
    archiveFilePatterns: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_NodeJS-Node.js With Grunt-CI/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    destinationFolder: .
    cleanDestinationFolder: false

Classic Editor:

Result:

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: ExtractFiles@1 - Extract files v1 task

It is useful to see your artifact mapping and its contents in the build. It is not clear which zip file you are trying to extract: your custom zip or the drop artifact. In the case of the drop artifact, the release should automatically extract all files. Check the log in the Download artifact step.
